# C project where i can dynamically select folders during compile time

Tags: architecture, build

Lets say my folder structure is something like this ..

+-- Application  
   | 
   +-- MICRO_CONTROLLER_1
   |
   +-- MICRO_CONTROLLER_2
   |
   +-- MICRO_CONTROLLER_3

and i have a compile time switch as #define SELECT_MICRO == MICRO_CONTROLLER_1 , then my project should build application with driver files in MICRO_CONTROLLER_1 , similarly if #define SELECT_MICRO == MICRO_CONTROLLER_2 , then application should  build application with driver files in MICRO_CONTROLLER_2

Please let me know if there template to achieve the above.